# Double summation: how to solve?

Tags: summation

I have this summation that I need to solve:

$$\sum_{i=2}^{n}\sum_{j=i}^{n} 3i$$

Can someone please help? I have no idea how to start this

Comment: Hint: use the algebraic sequence sum formula

Answer (score 2):

Just write it out explicitly to see what happens:

\begin{align}
\sum_{i=2}^{n}\sum_{j=i}^{n} 3i
&=\sum_{i=2}^{n} \underbrace{(3i+3i+\cdots +3i)}_{n-i+1 \textrm{ terms}}\\
&=\sum_{i=2}^n (n-i+1)(3i)\\
&=\sum_{i=2}^n 3n \cdot i - 3i^2+3i\\
&=\bigg((3n+3)\sum_{i=2}^ni\bigg)-3\bigg(\sum_{i=2}^ni^2\bigg)
\end{align}

Now work on the following:
$$
\sum_{i=2}^n i,\quad \sum_{i=2}^ni^2
$$